# Link in background image not working on IE

Tags: html, css

In my website, I've got a big image in the background, with negative z-index and position fixed. This image is clickable and on the top there's the main content of the website (it's like a so said "skin banner"). Everything works in FF, Chrome and Safari, but, as often happens, it doesn't work in IE... Can somebody help me? I would like to avoid the use of JS and if possible I would like to maintain the image definition inside the HTML instead of in the CSS (i'm talking about the "space" image). This is the code that replicates the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xml:lang="it-it"
      lang="it-it"
      dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title>TEST BACKGROUND IMAGE</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        background: #000 url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/AFM_image_of_tin_layer.jpg) repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        color: #333;
        font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        z-index: -10000;
        margin: auto;
        width: 980px;
    }

    .skin-banner
    {
        position: fixed;    
        z-index: -9000;
        width: 1280px;
        height: 920px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: -550px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #all
    {
        color: #333;
        border:solid 0px;
        padding-top:0px;
        background:#FFF;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .with_skin_on_top
    {
        margin-top: 60px !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="skin-banner">
    <div class="custom">
      <p>
        <a href="http://www.google.it" target="blank">
          <img src="http://www.redorbit.com/media/gallery/xmm-newton/cl-j14490856.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="all" class="with_skin_on_top">
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works in IE11

Comment: I also run IE11. Are you saying that you can click the "space" image in the portion on top and to the sides of the white box? This is what I need, but it doesn't seems to work in my browser.

Comment: Your right. it works only underneath the white box. - I have a look at it later...

Answer (score 0):

Try this js code will work for all images in IE that are in anchor tag   :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a input[type=button]').click(function(){
       window.location = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: this works for any buttons that are inside anchor tag as IE doesn`t support buttons inside anchor tag.You can change it for img tag if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

this works so far. just check the width of your img for correct positioning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xml:lang="it-it"
      lang="it-it"
      dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title>TEST BACKGROUND IMAGE</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        background: #000 url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/AFM_image_of_tin_layer.jpg) repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        color: #333;
        font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        z-index: -10000;
        margin: auto;
        width: 980px;
    }

    .skin-banner
    {
        position: fixed;    
        z-index: -9000;
        width: 1280px;
        height: 920px;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #all
    {
        color: #333;
        border:solid 0px;
        padding-top:0px;
        background:#FFF;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
        position:absolute;
        width: 980px;
        left:50px;
        top:0px;    
    }

    .with_skin_on_top
    {
        margin-top: 60px !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="skin-banner">
    <div class="custom">

      <p>
        <a href="http://www.google.it" target="blank">
          <img src="http://www.redorbit.com/media/gallery/xmm-newton/cl-j14490856.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
        </a>
      </p>

    </div>
      <div id="all" class="with_skin_on_top">
        <p>TEST</p>
      </div>       
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```